# In a dropdown, setting optgroup name as selected option text with JS not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, cross-browser

I have javascript that makes a `select` set the displayed selected text in a dropdown as the selected option's `<optgroup>` label but when the dropdown is open, it displays the text stored in `data-content` as the option text under the `<optgroup>` label. It works beautifully in Chrome but breaks in Firefox. When the select is clicked in Firefox, it starts opening and shutting so fast a selection cannot be made. I notice when I comment out the `$(this).blur` section the flickering stops but then the js obviously breaks. Thanks for any help you can offer!

You can view the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aimzatron/6hemv17n/2/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="car_choice">
  <optgroup label="Truck">
    <option data-value="truck" data-title="Truck" data-content="A description of a truck">
      Truck
    </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Car">
    <option data-value="car" data-title="Car" data-content="A description of a car">
      Car
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$('#car_choice option:selected').html($('#car_choice option:selected').attr('value'));

$("#car_choice").on('change mouseleave', function(){
  $('#car_choice option').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).attr('data-title'));
  });
  $('#car_choice option:selected').html($('#car_type_choice option:selected').attr('data-title'))
  $(this).blur();
});

$('#car_choice').on('focus', function(){
  $('#car_choice option').each(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).attr('data-content'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a gross solution but I solved it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aimzatron/f8bdukxr/)

```
$('#assignment_type_choice option:selected').html($('#assignment_type_choice option:selected').attr('value'));

var browser;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/i)) {
    browser = "chrome";
}
else {
    browser = "other";
}

$("#assignment_type_choice").on('click mouseup', function(){
    if(browser === "other"){
    $('#assignment_type_choice').each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).attr('data-title'));
    });
    $('#assignment_type_choice option:selected').html($('#assignment_type_choice option:selected').attr('data-title'))
   };
 });


$("#assignment_type_choice").on('change mouseleave', function(){
    console.log("browser is " + browser)
    if(browser === "chrome"){
    $('#car_choice option').each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).attr('data-title'));
    });
    $('#assignment_type_choice option:selected').html($('#assignment_type_choice option:selected').attr('data-title'))
 };
});

$('#assignment_type_choice').on('mousedown', function(){
  $('#assignment_type_choice option').each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).attr('data-content'));
  });
});
```